# Restart monit automatically after it has been killed by the system

Tags: monitoring, upstart, monit

I am using monit to monitor my WEB service. Everything went OK until monit process was killed by the system. There is a part of monit log file showing the issue

[image: monit log file]

To have monit automatically launched at startup and restarted on failure I added upstart config for monit (I am running Ubuntu 14.04), that looks like this:

```
    # This is an upstart script to keep monit running.
    # To install disable the old way of doing things:
    #
    #   /etc/init.d/monit stop && update-rc.d -f monit remove
    #
    # then put this script here:
    #
    #   /etc/init/monit.conf
    #
    # and reload upstart configuration:
    #
    #   initctl reload-configuration
    #
    # You can manually start and stop monit like this:
    # 
    # start monit
    # stop monit
    #

    description "Monit service manager"

    limit core unlimited unlimited

    start on runlevel [2345]
    stop on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[016]

    expect daemon
    respawn

    exec /usr/bin/monit -c /etc/monitrc

    pre-stop exec /usr/bin/monit -c /etc/monitrc quit
```

When I reboot the system monit is not running.

```
    sudo monit status
    $ monit: Status not available -- the monit daemon is not running
```

How can I configure upstart to keep monit running and monitored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the wrong path to the config file in the start monit command. The correct commands are

```
    exec /usr/bin/monit -c /etc/monit/monitrc

    pre-stop exec /usr/bin/monit -c /etc/monit/monitrc quit
```

It starts monit as daemon and restarts when I kill it:

```
    ps aux | grep monit
    root      2173  0.0  0.1 104348  1332 ?        Sl   04:13   0:00 /usr/bin/monit -c /etc/monit/monitrc

    sudo kill -9 2173

    ps aux | grep monit
    root      2184  0.0  0.1 104348  1380 ?        Sl   04:13   0:00 /usr/bin/monit -c /etc/monit/monitrc
```